# Fetch data in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, ios12

I have an error when I try to fetch data using Xcode 10 Beta and Swift 4.2.

In swift 4.1 was working perfect my method and now I have an error and I can't find a solution on internet to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
// Download photos from Google for products avatar
func fetchPhotosForProductsFromGoogle(){

    guard let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL.googleAPI + "q=\(query ?? "flagUK")" + URL.searchPhotosOnly + URL.googleSearchEngineID + URL.googleAPIKey)
        else{
            fatalError("URL can't be found.")
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestURL) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error URL Session.")
            return
        }
        do {

            let googlePhotosList = try JSONDecoder().decode(GoogleSearchModel.self, from: data!)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.productsTableView.reloadData()
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Here is a picture with the error:

[image]

Any idea will help me a lot ! Thanks.

Comment: Why did you needlessly start using `NSURL` instead of `URL`?

Comment: FYI - It would be much better to build your `URL` using `URLComponents` instead of all of that string manipulation, especially the query string.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you maddy. I go now to check how to do it with URLComponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a JSON Model where was a structure named URL and because of that structure the URL class from Swift was override. So be careful when you convert your JSON model into Swift to check 2 times the name of the structures, enums etc.

Answer (score 1):

Before swift 3 there was implicit bridging between between swift types and their counter types in objc but after swift 3 it is removed and you will have to be explicit while passing such type, refer [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md) for more details

So you can do this

```
with: requestURL as URL
```

Or Use URL instead of NSURL

Answer (score 0):

Change the `NSURL` to `URL` and I think you should be good to go:

```
guard let requestURL = URL(string: "someUrl.com")
    else{
        fatalError("URL can't be found.")
}
```

Comment: I use NSURL because I'm not able to use URL. When I open the brackets after URL then I have only this 2 options: https://ibb.co/ncFWEo

Answer (score 0):

In the left part you send the `URL` object but in the right it's `NSURL`

```
func dataTask(with url: URL) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

see here in  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411554-datatask)